# How can I change the settings of read only pendrive?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

```
pm@pm-desktop:~$ sudo lsblk -f
NAME           FSTYPE  LABEL UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
sdb                                                                 
└─sdb1         ntfs          80060C87060C8100                       /media/pm/80
sr0                                                                 
sda                                                                 
├─sda2                                                              
├─sda5         crypto_       e47293da-ef9b-4299-a0b5-e46339213365   
│ └─sda5_crypt LVM2_me       hoVHG1-FRUq-b6x1-dLl1-B1i8-8joH-MAKNkG 

    pm@pm-desktop:~$ sudo lsblk -m
NAME                      SIZE OWNER GROUP MODE
sdb                      14.9G root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sdb1                   14.9G root  disk  brw-rw----
sr0                      1024M root  cdrom brw-rw----
sda                     465.8G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda2                      1K root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda5                  465.3G root  disk  brw-rw----
│ └─sda5_crypt          465.3G root  disk  brw-rw----
│   ├─ubuntu--vg-root   463.3G root  disk  brw-rw----
│   └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1     2G root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sda1                    487M root  disk  brw-rw----

│   ├─ubuntu--vg-root
│   │          ext4          39a158a9-1eec-40d7-9edd-6c659f296210   /
│   └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1
│              swap          0f5d2da1-3bbe-439e-8b20-9097be917a36   [SWAP]
└─sda1         ext2          b76e49df-ef33-41cd-9201-dbc718f40ecc   /boot

pm@pm-desktop:~$ sudo parted -ls
Model: ATA ST3500418AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  512MB  511MB  primary   ext2         boot
 2      513MB   500GB  500GB  extended
 5      513MB   500GB  500GB  logical


Warning: Unable to open /dev/sdb read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sdb has been opened read-only.
Model: SanDisk Cruzer Switch (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 16.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  16.0GB  16.0GB  primary  ntfs


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 497GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  497GB  497GB  ext4


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 2110MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  2110MB  2110MB  linux-swap(v1)


Error: /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt: unrecognised disk label
Model: Linux device-mapper (crypt) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags: 
pm@pm-desktop:~$ df -h  
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                         961M     0  961M   0% /dev
tmpfs                        198M  6.2M  192M   4% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  456G   16G  418G   4% /
tmpfs                        987M   19M  969M   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                        987M     0  987M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                    472M  136M  312M  31% /boot
tmpfs                        198M   72K  198M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb1                     15G  8.7G  6.3G  59% /media/pm/80060C87060C8100
```

Comment: I had tried many methods mentioned in other answers but none worked. Please suggest something that works

Comment: This drive has no hardware switch to make it read only but is damaged a bit near the USB port

Comment: ~$ cat /proc/mounts | grep sdb
/dev/sdb1 /media/pm/80060C87060C8100 fuseblk ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0

Comment: Please add relevant information via [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1083275/edit) to your question instead of posting comments.

Comment: Please tell us what kind of pendrive it is. 1. brand name and model; 2. kind of partitions/{file systems}; 3. data drive, live drive, install drive; 4. If you modified the partitions/file systems: how you modified it (tool, method).

Comment: In order to help us help you, please edit your original question to add the output of the following commands, `sudo lsblk -f` and `sudo lsblk -m` and `sudo parted -ls` and `df -h` Please indent each line of the output 4 spaces in order to render it as 'code'.

Comment: I have included the commands and their outputs via edit as asked by @sudodus

Answer (score 0):

The USB pendrive is seen like this:

```
$ sudo parted -ls

Warning: Unable to open /dev/sdb read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sdb has been opened read-only.
Model: SanDisk Cruzer Switch (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 16.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:
```

and

```
$ sudo lsblk -f
NAME           FSTYPE  LABEL UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
sdb                                                                 
└─sdb1         ntfs          80060C87060C8100                       /media/pm/80...
sr0                                                                 

sudo lsblk -m
NAME                      SIZE OWNER GROUP MODE
sdb                      14.9G root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sdb1                   14.9G root  disk  brw-rw----
```

and is mounted as

```
$ df -h  
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1                     15G  8.7G  6.3G  59% /media/pm/80060C87060C8100
```

with read-only permissions. There can be different reasons for the read-only status.

---

**If there are important files on the USB pendrive, please back them up** (copy them to another drive) before you start any repair actions.

---

**Maybe the NTFS file system is damaged and needs to be repaired with Windows tools**, either the graphical tool in Windows or with

```
chkdsk /f X:
```

where X: is its volume ID as seen by Windows. See this link for more details,

[Repair the partition table and file system of a pendrive](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986)

After trying to repair the file system, you can try again in Ubuntu. **If it still does not want to mount it read-write, you can try according to the following** AskUbuntu answer,

[Mount NTFS partition in a USB drive with custom permissions and owner](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072)